# Unable to access Microsoft FACE API

Tags: api, face

I'm facing this issue today. Unable to access Microsoft FACE Api endpoint:

https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0

Anyone facing the same issue today? 
Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl5pv.png)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working for me. You need to add more to the URL for your API call.

FACE API is actually a family of 56 APIs. I just did a project using 9 APIs. At the end of the url, you need to add more... for example the face detect API is
https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?returnFaceId=true

More info here: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236